# Temporarily increase 'statement_timeout' for Postgres queries in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, timeout

I already configured my `statement_timeout` in `database.yml` to some seconds, but there are some expensive queries in my application, which require longer query execution times. What would be the recommended way to achieve this on a per-query level?
I would need to temporarily set the `statement_timeout` to a larger value, execute the query and reset it to the default value? Or is the resetting not even required?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think you can achieve that only by changing the `statement_timeout` for whole connection then revert it back:

```
  def execute_expensive_query
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET statement_timeout = 600000' # 10 minutes
    # DB query with long execution time
  ensure
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute 'SET statement_timeout = 5000' # 5 seconds
  end
```

On DB level, you can set `statement_timeout` for the current transaction only as per [this guide](https://github.com/ankane/the-ultimate-guide-to-ruby-timeouts#statement-timeouts-1):

```
BEGIN;
SET LOCAL statement_timeout = 250;
...
COMMIT;
```

Answer (score 11):

To expand on the accepted answer, here's how one could implement a module `DatabaseTimeout`, that also makes sure to reset the `statement_timeout` setting back to its original value.

```rb
# Ruby's `Timeout` doesn't prevent queries from running for a long time.
#
# To prove this, run the following in a console (yes, twice):
#   Timeout.timeout(1.second) { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(100);') }
#   Timeout.timeout(1.second) { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(100);') }
# => The 2nd call should run for a long time.
#
# DatabaseTimeout's purpose is to enforce that each query doesn't run for more than the given timeout:
#   DatabaseTimeout.timeout(1.second) { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(100);') }
#   DatabaseTimeout.timeout(1.second) { ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SELECT pg_sleep(100);') }
# => Both queries are interrupted after 1 second
module DatabaseTimeout
  # Usage: DatabaseTimeout.timeout(10) { run_some_query }
  def self.timeout(nb_seconds)
    original_timeout = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('SHOW statement_timeout').first['statement_timeout']
    ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET statement_timeout = '#{nb_seconds.to_i}s'")
    yield
  ensure
    if original_timeout
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET statement_timeout = '#{original_timeout}'")
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: Need single quotes around the original_timeout in the ensure

Comment: How does this deal with transactions? It appears that the SHOW statement_timeout then a connection.execute and then the actual transacted-query would cause issues. Or am I misunderstanding how Rails  handles this in transactions?

Comment: @berkes When `DatabaseTimeout.timeout` is called inside a transaction, the SHOW statement and the 2 SET statements are part of the transaction, which I think is not an issue.

Comment: @MatthieuLibeer thanks. But that means you have to wrap all `DatabaseTimeout.timeout` in a database transaction, or run the risk of polluting concurrent queries (on the same AR connection) with the altered timeout, not?

Answer (score 6):

As @berkes pointed out, you run the risk of polluting concurrent queries on the same AR connection with the accepted answer (e.g. we ran into issues when using the above with PgBouncer). So it should be run in a transaction. This is what I wrote for use at my company:

```rb
module DatabaseTimeout
  module_function

  # Usage: DatabaseTimeout.timeout(10) { run_some_query }
  def timeout(nb_seconds)
    ActiveRecord::Base.transaction do
      ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute("SET LOCAL statement_timeout = '#{nb_seconds.to_i}s'")
      yield
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: This is super handy, thanks for this. One note: `statement_timeout` does not accept units, as far as I can tell. Units are ms. Not sure if this is config-related or postgres-version related.